# How to use image as an input for TFLite model?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a model in Keras then saved it and converted it to a TFLite file. To test my Keras model I was using the following code to convert an image to numpy arrays:

```
img_path = r'path'
img = image.load_img(img_path, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(img_height, img_width))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = numpy.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img.reshape(1, img_width, img_height, 1)
```

Which put it into a 4d array of the shape (1, 224, 224, 1). My question is how do I prepare data in the same way for a TFLite model on Android? And does the TFLite file require the data to be in the same format?